# Mac OSx Yosemite trouble to boot

Tags: macos, mac, fsck

My MacBook Pro doesn't start suddently. After following lot of posts i tried single user login, Disk Utility etc

```
* Disk utility shows no errors its always successful.

* fsck -fy gives me the following error

CoreStorageGroup::completeIORequest - error 0xe00002ca detected for LVG  
"Macintosh HD" (EE74B25C-0D2C-49B5-BF7D-EFF4D0D4EA18), pv F035EDD4-32D0-
4718-B83B-2D61C774E567, near LV byte offset = 320161787904.
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using safe boot? ( hold the shift key when you hear your Mac starts up and hold it till you see the apple logo)

Comment: S i tried that a lot. but iam unable to get in to safe boot\

Comment: Have you tried to see what verbose mode shows

Comment: Whats the use in verbose mode ? Its almost same as single user mode right ?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct. Single user mode turns the computer on using bash. Verbose mode will use the normal startup process and it shows you all the loading kernels and startup tasks.